# Authentification Android with spring boot security

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to do authentification from my app android by using spring boot I try to send the username and password like this:

```
HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password);
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

and make network request using restTemplate.exchange :

```
ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Message.class);
```

but I still get null response.

This my code server :

**Controller**:

```
@Controller  
public class RController {  

@RequestMapping(value={"/welcome"})
public @ResponseBody Message getMessage() { 
return new Message(100, "Congratulations!", "You have accessed a Basic 
    Auth protected resource.");
}

@RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
    public String login() {
    return "login";
} }
```

**config**

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
        .permitAll();
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes,but I forgot the solution, because i moved to another project :/  sorry man